# Analogue of spectral gap but for *smallest* eigenvalues/singular values

Tags: pca, references, markov-process

The difference between the largest eigenvalue and the next-largest of a graph Laplacian (equivalently, of the random walk Markov chain on the graph) is the spectral gap, related to the Cheeger constant, etc. Is there any interpretation of the difference between the smallest two eigenvalues of the graph?

I am equally interested in the interpretation of the gap between the smallest and next-smallest singular values of a matrix.

Comment: Do you have a statistical contwxt for the Q? Otherwise, it might be beyter migrayed math SE

Comment: The question did come out of a probabilistic engineering problem (optimal control of variance) but it seemed distracting. But it seems that the difference between the smallest two PCA weights is an item that statisticians might come across in characterizing the behavior of estimators etc. If it's better migrated I'm happy to do it.

Comment: Please add the context to the question, it might help answerers.  Context is never optional in statistics!